# how to find employee who is absent continuously more than 10 days?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table name Att. which has 2 columns: EmpID and Date.
the date column contains all the dates an employee is present.
i need write a query to find if any employee is **continuously** absent for more than 10 days.

```
EmpID | Date
  101 | 1/1/2012
  101 | 2/1/2012
  101 | 7/1/2012
  101 | 18/1/2012
  101 | 21/1/2012
  101 | 25/1/2012
  101 | 30/1/2012
  102 | 1/1/2012
  102 | 2/1/2012
  102 | 5/1/2012
  102 | 9/1/2012
  102 | 14/1/2012
  102 | 19/1/2012
  102 | 24/1/2012
  102 | 25/1/2012
  102 | 28/1/2012
  102 | 29/1/2012
  102 | 30/1/2012
```

the result should 101 here.
how this can be done? please help.

Comment: you should just fire him.

Comment: @ weaselfox... maybe i should, thats why i need this query to find him from thousands of employee.
@JW. why minus bro? i was just editing and saw its been edited already. :(

Comment: nope, i didn't vote yet.

Comment: what version of sql server you are using?

Comment: sql server 2005, so sorry to missed that

Comment: Does this have to handle weekends?

Answer (score 3):

if you are working with `SQL Server 2012`, you can use `LEAD` Analytical Function

```
WITH recordList
AS
(
  SELECT EmpID, Date FromDate,
         LEAD(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY Date ASC) ToDate
  FROM   tableName
)
SELECT DISTINCT EmpID
FROM recordList 
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, FromDate ,ToDate) >= 10
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/808d6/2)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*others*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/808d6/3)

Other Link(s)

- [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)
- [LEAD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx)

**UPDATE 1**

```
WITH firstList
AS
(
  SELECT EmpID, Date,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY Date ASC) RN
  FROM   tableName
)
SELECT  DISTINCT a.EmpID
FROM    firstList a
        INNER JOIN firstList b
          ON a.RN + 1 = b.RN
WHERE   DATEDIFF (d, a.Date , b.Date ) >= 10
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/808d6/10)

Comment: exactly this thing needed but in sql server 2005.

Comment: @JW secondList is redundant, the final query can just have `firstlist a INNER JOIN firstList b ON a.RN+1=b.RN`

Comment: @DaleM yeah, i didn't think of that. grr (*due to overthinking* hahaha). I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to use a subquery. Something like

```
select * from Att a1
where day(a1.date)-10 > all
(select day(a2.date) from Att a2 where a2.empid = a1.empid and a2.date < a1.date)
```

The idea is that we select a row who's date, even if we subtract 10 days, is still greater than the date of all rows that occured earlier chronologically before it, for the same EmpID.

`day(date)` should be the function that returns the number of days that have occured since the epoch, NOT the day of the month or day of the week. Alternatively, you could do something like `date-10*ticksinday`. Whatever you do will depend on your SQL flavour :)

Once this makes sense to you, implement it.

Answer (score 1):

One more option with OUTER APPLY and EXISTS

```
SELECT t1.[EmpID], t1.[Date], o.[EmpID], o.[Date],
       DATEDIFF(d, o.[Date], t1.[Date]) AS diff        
FROM TableName t1 
OUTER APPLY (
             SELECT t2.[EmpID], t2.[Date]
             FROM TableName t2
             WHERE EXISTS (
                           SELECT 1
                           FROM TableName t3
                           WHERE  t1.[Date] > t3.[Date] 
                             AND t1.EmpID = t2.EmpID
                           HAVING MAX(t3.[Date]) = t2.[Date]
                           ) 
             ) o
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, o.[Date], t1.[Date]) >= 10
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bde49/1/0)